# Is SQLite 3.7.11 100% backward-compatible with 3.7.7?

Tags: sqlite

Willing to use SQLite 3.7.11 everywhere instead of 3.7.7 and having found no up-to-date PPA for this, I've just replaced `/usr/bin/sqlite3` file in my XUbuntu 11.10 system with the updated one. So I am curious: aren't there any incompatibilities between 3.7.7 and 3.7.11 that can cause problems in applications expecting 3.7.7 to be installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to the database files, then no there aren't any incompabilities. All such incompabilities are listed here:

http://www.sqlite.org/formatchng.html